# What are the x, y, and z in the /testforblocks command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've recently heard about a command which can detect blocks in an area, the `/testforblocks` (with an *s* at the end, to not confuse with `/testforblock`) command. In this command, there the x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, but also a supplementary x y z:

```
testforblocks <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <x> <y> <z> [mode]
```

Because of this little detail, I can't complete my small project. Thank you very much paying attention at my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first set of coordinates (`x1/y1/z1` to `x2/y2/z2`) are the bounding box of the initial structure, while the supplementary `x/y/z` coordinates are the lower north-west corner of the location you want to compare to.

In the following image, the yellow glass represents `x1/y1/z1`, the blue glass represents `x2/y2/z2`, and the white glass represents `x/y/z` (assuming the player is facing north):

[image: Left: initial, right: target]

The command specifically compares two structures rather than searching for a block anywhere in the area. In the image (if replacing the glass with redstone blocks), the two structures do not match because the target structure is missing a block in the middle (which must be a redstone block instead), so the command fails.

Comment: So it's mean that if I add a clock to the command block plus the comparator, the command will serve at nothing? So outside of the command, how do I use it? I do simply put a comparator and power the command block?